# Is it possible to use other languages than Javascript in CouchDB show/list functions

Tags: couchdb

CouchDB delegates computation of Views to external query servers. So it is possible to use other languages than Javascript for MapReduce functions (for example, there is implementations for Common Lisp, native Erlang, etc.)

Is it possible to do so with CouchDB Show/List functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible (even on a per-view basis) and is described on this page of the CouchDB wiki:

http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_server

Once you define additional query servers in your `local.ini` you're good to go and even Futon (the included `/_utils` web interface) will give you a dropdown to select a language from.